# Check is chrome extensions installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome extension published on Chrome web store.

Now I want to implement Inline installation from page on my website.

I was following this[chrome tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

So I added my website as verified site for my Chrome extension and inline installation is working fine.

The issue which I have is how to check does user already have my extension installed.

I want to first check does user have extension installed and if so don't show installation button and otherwise to show it.

In chrome tutorial for inline installation there is [explanation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#already-installed) how to check is extension already installed by checking `chrome.app.isInstalled`

But this is always returning **false**, even if extension is installed.
I cannot find any detail explanation of using this property. I am wondering how it even conclude which extension I am checking? Does it conclude from chrome `<link>` in `head`:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

Any help, how properly to check does user have my extension installed or not?

Comment: `chrome.app.isInstalled` is intended for installed Chrome web apps, not for extensions (these are [different things](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions)). See [this answer in FAQs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-app-24). You need to use web accessible resource as Mottie suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a security video on YouTube, I don't have a link anymore, but I think it was a DefCon talk, or something... it shows how Chrome allows access to extension resources from a browser URL if the resource is included in the extension list of [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in the `manifest.json`. This probably isn't a good thing...

So potentially you could:

- Create an image that says something like the extension is installed and active.
- Add this image to your extension, and include it in the `manifest.json` under the `web_accessible_resources` list.
- Then link to it on your webpage. The image will only be visible if the extension is installed *and* enabled.

  ```
  <img src="chrome-extension://{extension-id}/extension-enabled.png">
  ```
- Use javascript to check and see if the image loaded. If it didn't, replace it with a url showing that the extension is disabled or not-installed.