# how to check if my extension is installed on the browser where a specific web-page is visited?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon-webextensions, opera-extension

I have gone through [Check is chrome extensions installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37690171), https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930310 and also some other questions in stack-overflow. but i could only make it work for chrome but not all browsers at a time. Can anyone help me detect if my extension is installed when ever a website is visited. I have implemented solution as mentioned in second url posted above. but it worked only for chrome. I wanted to detect extension in any browser where i visit xyz url.

Comment: "Check chrome extension" in IE and Firefox sounds a bit like a waste of time

Comment: hm, your extension could add a hidden div to your page. On your Javascriptside you can check if the div is there.

Comment: @MThiele Thanks for helping. I have tried that with an <img> attribute instead of div. But in javascript i had to access that file using path which is a problem here as chrome extensions have different path than firefox ones.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox a webextension's content script can use the `cloneInto` API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.cloneInto) to insert code into a web page's script context where then e.g. a global variable can be written into the window object to identify the extension is installed.